# How to force python float operation on float32 rather than float64?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, operators, precision

I want to do some math operations (+, -, *, /) on `float32` rather than on `float64` type. I need do these operations on `number` or `numpy.array`, and also some numpy math functions, such as `sqrt mean`. How do I do this?

Comment: [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Will numpy.float32 help?

```
>>>PI=3.1415926535897
>>> print PI*PI
9.86960440109
>>> PI32=numpy.float32(PI)
>>> print PI32*PI32
9.86961
```

If you want to do math operation on float32, convert the operands to float32 may help you.

Comment: Yes. numpy.float32 can help me. Are there any other methods to do this

Comment: Yes, when using an array you can call it's astype method if it is not float32: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html

Answer (score 1):

Use [numpy.ndarray.astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr_f64 = np.array([1.0000123456789, 2.0000123456789, 3.0000123456789], dtype=np.float64)
arr_f32 = arr_f64.astype(np.float32)
```

Pay attention to precision:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=16)
print("arr_f64 = ", arr_f64)
print("arr_f32 = ", arr_f32)
```

gives

```
arr_f64 =  [1.0000123456789 2.0000123456789 3.0000123456789]
arr_f32 =  [1.0000124000000 2.0000124000000 3.0000124000000]
```