# Revisit forcing python math functions to operate on float32

Tags: math, numpy, theano

I am aware of howto force python operations to work on float32:
[How to force python float operation on float32 rather than float64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768590/how-to-force-python-float-operation-on-float32-rather-than-float64)

But there is no Q or A about forcing the built in functions to work on float32. 
I wanted to ask how about forcing the built-in math or numpy functions such as math.sqrt or numpy.sqrt to work on float32. FYI, I could not comment on the question yet.

In theano, we can easily configure the function, e.g., sqrt to work on float32 or float64 as follows:

```
from theano import config
config.floatX = 'float32'
from theano import tensor as T
x = T.scalar()
a = T.sqrt(x)

from theano import function
h = function([x], a)
print h(15)
```

and the result is:

```
3.87298345566
```

Now I tried to force math.sqrt and numpy.sqrt to do the same as follows:

```
import math
import numpy
print math.sqrt(numpy.float32(15))
```

But the result is still seems in float64 (I confirmed it 
that the result would be the same, i.e., 3.87298334621,
if I set theano.config.floatX='float64'):

```
3.87298334621
```

I am curious to know howto force math.sqrt, numpy.sqrt to work on float32?

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> type(numpy.sqrt(numpy.float32(2)))
<type 'numpy.float32'>
```

`numpy.sqrt` already does what you want. On the other hand, the `math` functions always cast their input to `float` and return `float`, with no option to change that. Stick with NumPy operations instead of the `math` module for NumPy data types, and you should be fine.